# Qt 5.0 convert mouse to world coordinates

Tags: qt, opengl

I am working on Qt 5.0 opengl application.

I need to convert mouse coordinate to world coordinate.

Does Qt 5.0 supports any mouse function to do this?

let me know what would be the best way to do to achieve this.

Comment: Assuming you mean global coords when you say "world", you need to tell us from what coordinate frame you are converting e.g. widget coordinates.

Comment: @fsw: World coordinate is a very standard term in OpenGL terminology, the question is actually very clear.

Comment: @cmannett85: same here ;-)

Comment: Are you using only 2D OpenGL or 3D OpenGL? You have to be aware than in 3D, things are not as easy as it may seem, and this conversion is ambiguous. More precisely, there are an infinite number of possible 3D points that correspond to you mouse, which are along a line going from the camera to the background.